# terminating further execution of jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm at the begining of my jQuery jouerny and I still have difficult times understanding some basic topics so I decided to make a simple script with just a few lines of PHP to try some things. I have a main page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> TEST </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>


        <a  href = "http://www.abv.bg/" class="isLogged">abv.bg</a>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <a  href = "http://www.yahoo.com/" class="isLogged">Yahoo!</a>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <a href = "http://www.southparkstudios.com/" class="isLogged">South Park</a>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <a  href = "http://www.youtube.com/" class="isLogged">Youtube</a>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <a  href = "http://www.vbox7.com/" class="isLogged">Vbox</a>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <a  href = "http://www.sa.dir.bg/" class="isLogged">Dir.BG</a>
        <br />

        <div class="isLogged"> hi<div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        var Status = <?php echo $_SESSION['isLogged'] ?>
                        $('.isLogged').click(function(){
                            if(Status!=true){
                                var Check = prompt('Enter Password', '');
                                $.post('check.php', {Check:Check}, function(data) {  var result = data;
                                    alert(result); exit;
                                });

                            }


                        });


                    }); 
                </script>
                </body>
                </html>
```

the improtant part is in the  tags. As you can see I want to make a very simple check if user has entered a password and to let him open link with class="isLogged" if he is. What I have hard time to understan is how to manage my php side script, here is what I have now:

```
<?php session_start();
$data = $_POST['Check'];
$yes = "[{data}]";
$no = 'N';
if ($data != 'Ivan')
{

echo json_encode($yes);
}
else
{

$_SESSION['isLogged'] = true;
}
?>
```

But I don't know how to format my data on the PHP side so I can make a proper check in the script. However I've reached that far that at least `echo json_encode($yes);` so I use it to make my check, but still, I can not find out how to prevent the link from loading.
  So it makes a lot of questions buthope it's not that hard to get the correct answers.

thanks

Leron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this. I think this is what you're trying to do: check for the correct password before allowing the user to proceed to the link that was clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var Status = <?php echo (bool)$_SESSION['isLogged']; ?>

        $('.isLogged').click(function(){

            if(!Status)
            {
                var Check = prompt('Enter Password', '');
                var Success = false;

                $.post('check.php', {Check:Check}, function(data) {

                    var response = $.parseJSON(data);

                    if(response.result)
                    {
                        Success = true;
                    }
                });

                /*
                    If you return false in a .click() it stops the link being visited. The browser won't follow the href.
                    So here, if the password was wrong, Success will be false and thus the link won't be visited
                */
                return Success;
            }

        });

    }); 
</script>
```

PHP side:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $out = array('result' => false);

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $password = 'Ivan';
        $input = $_POST['Check'];

        if(strcmp($input, $password) === 0) // case sensitive string comparison,  0 = strings are same
        {
            $_SESSION['isLogged'] = true;
            $out['result'] = true;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($out);

?>
```

Disclaimer: I appreciate this is a learning exercise rather than an actual system, this is obviously not a secure way of protecting content because we can't stop the user from browsing the link if they want to, or disabling javascript.

Comment: Thanks, you got my idea right. And I understand that it's not fit for a public purposes but is a fairly simple example with a lot of jquery basics in it at the same time. At least it is for me. However, the prompt box doesn't appear when I click somethin usgin your code :(

Comment: Sorry, my bad, a previous seession was still alive. It works flawless, exactly waht I need, gonna look over your code carefully. Thanks a lot for the help!!!!